# git svn fetch does not fetch a Subversion commit message modified after initial clone

Tags: git-svn

I cloned a large SVN repository (nearly 8,000 commits) and it seems to be OK.

Since then, the commit messages of about 20 Subversion commit messages have been changed to correct a typo.  This was done legitimately.  However, git svn fetch does not pull the updated commit messages.  It still displays the old outdated commit message.

Is there a way to fix this?  Preferably in a clean way and without hacking my local git repository too much?

I've tried git svn fetch -r 1234 (where 1234 is a known revision number).  But no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repair git-svn history when the commit message of a svn commit changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319673/how-to-repair-git-svn-history-when-the-commit-message-of-a-svn-commit-changes)

Answer (score 1):

from http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn:

> **git svn reset**
>
> Undoes the effects of fetch back to the specified revision. This allows
>   you to re-fetch an SVN revision.
>
> [...]
>
> Follow reset with a fetch and then git
>   reset or git rebase to move local
>   branches onto the new tree.

So in your case, if revision 1234 is the first one that had its commit message changed, you would do

```
$ git svn reset -p 1234
$ git svn fetch
```

If anything is different, including the commit message, then the new commit is a totally different object, with a new SHA1, so as it says, you'll need to rebase any branches you might have onto the appropriate rewritten commit.