# How to repair git-svn history when the commit message of a svn commit changes?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I use `git-svn` to connect to a subversion server. It seems to be possible to change the subversion commit message (of an old commit). See the accepted answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-log-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion) or [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105226/why-cant-i-edit-an-svn-commit-message). However `git svn rebase` does not notice such change.

How can I tell `git svn` to "repair" such changes in its history?

---

At first I did not notice that my history was broken by still containing the old commit message until I added a remote. This remote is another `git-svn` checkout of the same server. When one of the two checkouts updates (using `git svn rebase`) before the commit message in svn is changed and the other updates after the change, then the `git-svn` branch will point to different SHA-1 hashes in my repository and the remotes repository. That is one of the `git-svn` branch pointer is wrong and needs to be resynchronized/repaired:

```
            / C  - D  - E  - F
.... - A - B
            \ C' - D' - E' - F'
              ^
         commit-message
         later changed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git svn reset -r <n>` to reset (where `<n>` is a Subversion revision; see [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn-emresetem)):

> **reset**
>
> Undoes the effects of fetch back to the specified revision. This allows you to re-fetch an SVN revision. [...] Follow reset with a fetch and then git reset or git rebase to move local branches onto the new tree.

## Example

```
$ git svn find-rev B
3
$ git svn reset -r3
r3 = 6f29012a3e25e00c899976b584084d6968aba43d (refs/remotes/git-svn)
$ git svn fetch
...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have any local commits on top of the Subversion revisions, you could do a reset and then re-run svn rebase:

```
git reset --hard B
git svn rebase
```

If you do have local commits, I would try an interactive rebase, then re-run the svn rebase:

```
git rebase -i B
<A text editor will popup and you can remove the individual svn revisions there>
git svn rebase
```

If the change was to something a long time ago in svn's history though, I might try just editing that one message in git to be identical and see if git-svn will accept that.